# How do I target the search bar from a Firefox extension?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I'm new to building extensions -- and would like some help with knowing how to target the standard Google search bar that comes with Firefox..

I am thinking I have to find out which meni ID it is and assign it somehow within the .xul file..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From chrome (normally overlay of the chrome://browser/content/browser.xul) you can get access to search bar by getting it with document.getElementById('searchbar') The best way to find ids you need is by using Dom Inspector: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dom-inspector-6622/

Anyhow, if you want to access inner dom elements of the searchbar you'll need to use [getAnonymousElementByAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XBL/XBL_1.0_Reference/DOM_Interfaces#getAnonymousElementByAttribute) because that's anonymous content (from XBL binding). So if you need to get input element itself (where you're typing your search terms) you'll do it something like this from chrome:

```
var searchbarElement = document.getElementById('searchbar');
var input = document.getAnonymousElementByAttribute(searchbarElement, 'anonid', 'input');
```

You'll need to use Dom Inspector to figure out which element you need and how to access it.