# How can a Firefox extension detect when user searches with search bar?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

Is it possible for a Firefox extension to hook the browser-provided search bar so that when the user performs a search, a callback function (provided by the extension) receives the search query and which search engine was used?

I was able to find information on what XUL element contains the search bar text box ( [How do I target the search bar from a Firefox extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661699/how-do-i-target-the-search-bar-from-a-firefox-extension) ) but that's as far as I was able to get.

Answer (score 0):

The searchbar element has a bunch of methods defined by an XBL file at `chrome://browser/content/search/search.xml`. The function you're interested in would be `doSearch(query, where, engine)`. Simply overriding it seems to work well:

```
// in the context of a loaded browser window…
let bar = document.getElementById("searchbar");
let doSearch = bar.doSearch;
bar.doSearch = function(query, where, engine) {
    // your code here! e.g. console.log(query, where, engine);
    // don't forget to call the original function:
    doSearch(query, where, engine);
};
```

A complete example would be the [Clear Search](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/clear-search-2/) extension.